# whois.whois(domain) is not returning the domain registrar in for loop

Tags: python

I want to check the registrar for X thousand domains listed in the txt file. I do it with a for loop, but it returns to me the registrar only for the last record - no matter if there are 10 or 10,000 domains in the file.

Forgot something? Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

```
with open("domenytxt.txt") as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        rejestr = whois.whois(line).registrar
        print(rejestr)
```

Comment: You mean it only prints one record? Check `print(line)`.